# Using Log4Net Without DLL

Tags: c#, winforms, embed, log4net

My C# WinForms application is designed to be simple to deploy and I don't like the fact that the log4net.dll becomes an additional file to deploy.  Is there a way I can embed it into my application so all the user gets to see if the main .exe file and the backend SQL CE database?

Comment: _"I don't like the ... additional file to deploy"_  Get used to it, this is how the framework works.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I get that that is how it works, but when designing the application I have to think about the end users as well.

Comment: The end user will get a new folder and not care too much about what's in there.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You can do that using [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630).

> ILMerge is a utility that can be used to merge multiple .NET assemblies into a single assembly. ILMerge takes a set of input assemblies and merges them into one target assembly. The first assembly in the list of input assemblies is the primary assembly. When the primary assembly is an executable, then the target assembly is created as an executable with the same entry point as the primary assembly.

[Here's a GUI](http://ilmergegui.codeplex.com/) for ILMerge to make things easier for you

Comment: You're welcome. [Here's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9364/Merging-NET-assemblies-using-ILMerge) a tutorial to get you started.

Answer (score -1):

Well, as a side approach (other than ILMerge),

You can log everything in your server where you have deployed your application using log4net. When you want to retrieve your log, use Webrequest to get the data from the server.

Provided everything will need internet connection to log.